# Automatically getting a new access token on expiry using koala, but I don't use an app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I only use koala to query the Graph API explorer, and I do not have an app, so I do not have an app secret. Is it still possible for me to renew my access token on expiry? That way, I can run my code overnight instead of having two hour intervals.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in then docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

You'll need an app to be able to renew the Access Token. But that's not a real hurdle IMHO.